# How to do animation in 20 seconds later using swift? animateWithDuration:delay: is useless

Tags: ios, swift, animation

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10, delay: 20, options: .TransitionNone, animations: {

    }) { (let finish) in
        print("finish")
    }
```

Like the code shown, i want to print "finish" after 20 seconds, however i get it immediately.

By the way, how many ways to do make operations delay?

Comment: I really want to know why animateWithDuration:delay: is useless. I mean, its  what the delay parameter do, like the document said: **The amount of time (measured in seconds) to wait before beginning the animations. Specify a value of 0 to begin the animations immediately.**

Comment: i did some testing, and it seems if the animation block is empty, it just jumps to the completion immediately, strange behaviour, but maybe its some kind of optimisation

Comment: @Fonix I can confirm that the animation block must not be empty in order to work _as expected_. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Method: `NSTimer`**

```
func myDelayedFunction() {
    print("delayed")
}

func myMainFunction() {
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "myDelayedFunction", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    timer.fire()
}
```

**Second Method: `performSelector`**

```
func myDelayedFunction() {
    print("delayed")
}

func myMainFunction() {
    performSelector("myDelayedFunction", withObject: self, afterDelay: 10)
}
```

**Third Method: `GCD` (useful if you want an anonymous function)**
(adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924892/nstimer-with-anonymous-function-block))

```
let delayInSeconds: Int64 = 3
let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print("Delayed") 
}
```

**Fourth Method: `sleep`**

```
func myMainFunction() {
    sleep(10) //This will block whichever thread you're running on.
    print("delayed")
}
```

I tend to use the first method, because I can always invalidate the timer if I need to (calling `timer.invalidate`). Each method has its use case, though.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont actually need to do any animation, can use GCD to accomplish this

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(20 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()){
     print("finish")
};
```

you can make a neat little helper function as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/1219956) as well

Answer (score 1):

I think, there's a misconception. In your code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 20, options: [], animations: {
    // define animations
    self.myView.alpha = 0  // as an example
}) { (finish) in
    print("finish")
}
```

the completion handler will be called, when the animation finished. It starts after `delay` seconds (20.0) and takes `duration` seconds (10.0). That is, the animation should be completed after 30 seconds measured from the method call.

(You can place `NSLog` statements in your code to see when things happen)

I cannot reproduce what you are experiencing, that "finish" will be printed immediately. However, I can confirm that `UIView.animateWithDuration` works as expected - given the animation block is actually not empty.